# Navigation with scrolling viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to understand how to implement a navigation bar that transitions to the next view controller by swiping left and right.

The view controller enters the screen through a scroll.

Swipe left 
[image]

Go from "new" to "categories"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use UISwipeGesture.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Select whatever direction you need for swipe.

Here instead of [self view] you can pass reference of your view's reference.

OR

You can use pagination if you are using ScrollView

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. So how would I get the navbar to move with the pageviewcontroller